# Convert/Cast Error, NVARCHAR to INT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I'm using SQLServer 2008 R2.  I have two tables, the first is an attribute table.  The second has a column that references the attributes table.  The two tables are joined using a `varchar(32)` column.

```
#tblA                              #tblB
---------------------              ---------------------
attrib varchar(32)    <--------->  attrib varchar(32)
val nvarchar(255)                  [other fields]
[other fields]
```

The query joins the tables and casts `#tblA.val` as an `int`:

```
create table #tblA (attrib varchar(32), val nvarchar(255) /*, other fields */)
insert into #tblA values ('vase', 'red'), ('x', '323'), ('y', '615')

create table #tblB (attrib varchar(32) /*, other fields */)
insert into #tblB values ('x'), ('y')

select b.*, cast(a.val as int) as int_val
from   #tblA a inner join #tblB b on a.attrib = b.attrib

drop table #tblB, #tblA
```

This example works:

```
attrib                           int_val
-------------------------------- -----------
x                                323
y                                615
```

However, when I run the same query against my production tables with thousands of records, I get the error: <kbd>Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'vase' to data type int.</kbd>

**If I remove the `cast()` from my production query, I can see the returned data for column `val` only includes integer values.**

Why does SQL Server try to convert values that are not part of the returned dataset?  Even more odd, if I include `a.val` in the select list in addition to the `cast(a.val as int)`, there are no conversion errors.  Has anyone seen this before?  Is it just a bug in SQL Server?

BTW - Using `convert(int, a.val)` has the same problem as `cast(a.val as int)`.

Comment: You should get no matching rows using the given data above. If you change the 2nd table insert to insert into #tblB values ('vase'), ('bottom') - An error is correctly raised.

Comment: Sorry -- I tweaked the example before posting the question.  Didn't notice that 'top' and 'bottom' were still being inserted into #tblB.  I meant to use 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: Not really sure why you are getting this, but may be there are matching rows with non-numeric data (for example, some data may have special characters that don't display) or some leading blanks or null values. Another possibility may be that the value in the matched row exceeds the int limits. I guess you could easily verify these 2 cases quickly.

Comment: Already verify all all of that.  The way it's working today is, I do a `select ... into #temp`, then do a `select ..., cast(a.val as int) from #temp`, which works.  So the values are converting correctly if I push them to a #temp table first and then do the `cast()`.  So all of the data is valid.  For some reason SQL Server just tries to convert non-returned rows.  Seems like a bug in SQL Server to me, but thought I'd post the question here to see of anyone has seen this and knows why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be relevant to your issue. Please check the accepted answer. It is not a SQL Server bug. It is because the sequence of operations is not procedural (which is not very obvious to most).

[Cast Order in SQL Server Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305823/mssql-cast-varcharcolumn-to-int-in-select-gets-executed-before-where-clause)

Hope this helps.